# Eloquent eager loading does not return related model data

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project I have two Eloquent Models `Set` and `Card`, they have one to many relationship between them. `Set` has many `Cards` and `Cards` belong to `Set`.

I'm trying to pull the data using Eloquent Eager Loading using the `with()` function. But for some reason the `cards` array inside `sets` is returning as blank `[]`.

**Set.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Card;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Set extends Model
{
    protected $table = "sets";

    public function cards() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Card');
    }
}
```

**Card.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Set;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cards";

    public function sets() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Set');
    }
}
```

**Controller code**

```
$sets = Set::with([
         'cards' => function($query){
         $query->select('name', 'description');
         },
       ])->get();

  return $sets;
```

`name` and `description` are the fields that I have in `Cards` table except of the primary key and foreign key.

It returns with `"cards": []` in my `JSON` array of `sets`.

I have tried using below code in controller,

```
$sets = Set::with('cards.*')->get();

return $sets;
```

Did not work.

Tried adding the foreign key (set_id which is in the Cards table)  in the `hasMany` method in my `Set` model that creates relationship with `Cards` table. But of no result.

To be mentioned, when I tried pulling the data from `Cards` table separately from my `CardController`, it returned all `Cards` data.

Some clue would mean great help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: in tinker what does fetching a card out and checking $card->sets return?

Comment: Exception with message 'Property [sets] does not exist on this collection instance.'
.this is what I got

Comment: ^ This error doesn't make any sense with the code you've posted; you're not calling `->sets` anywhere. Please post your full code. Also, if you are getting that error, make sure you're looping your `Collection`. You can't call `$cards->sets` (if `$cards` is a `Collection`), but `$card->sets` (where `$card` is a single `Card` instance) is perfectly fine. Lastly, your relation name should represent what is being returned. `belongsTo` returns 1 `Set` model, or `null`, so calling it `sets` (plural) is wrong, it should be `set`.

Comment: Turned it the wrong way around Set::all()->first()->cards ?

Comment: can you tell a bit more ? @mrhn

Comment: im not sure your relation works, can you get it to work in tinker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your controller,

```
$sets = Set::with('cards')->get();

return $sets;
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 public function sets() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Set','id','id_set');
}
```

the second parameter "id" is the id of table Set, and the third parameter "id_set" is the foreing key in the Card Table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still returns blank. Maybe I tried this before.

Comment: Try instance :
 $set = Set::find($id);
 $card = $set->card(); // here give all card from the specific set

Comment: Yeah, the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `belongsTo` and `hasOne` (or `hasMany`) is optional and only needed if you use different columns than the ones Laravel assumes (id for primary, `{model}_id` for foreign)